# Socket broadcast to all clients on jQuery UI drop

Tags: jquery-ui, socket.io

**Problem**

When a user `drags and drops` an element, using `jQuery UI`, I would like to `broadcast` the `drop` to other users so they can see the updated position of the `element`.

**Question**

How can I configure the script to be able to send the 'dropping' of the element using `socket.broadcast.emit`?

**Code**

Client Side (the drop setup)

```
$('#dropArea').droppable({

    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);

        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(droppedOn);

        socket.emit('status', {
          status: 'ToDo', 
          _id: $(this).find('p').data('id') 
        });

    }
});
```

**Server** (some socket setup)

```
io.sockets.on('status', function(data) {
    Item.findOne({_id: data._id}, function(err, item) {
      if(err) throw err;
      item.status = data.status;
      item.save();
    });
  });
```

**Note**

The `emit` "status" updates the elements status in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a method. I sent the the relevant data required for the item in an object, through a socket.

On the server, I did the status update I needed from the mongoDB and then broadcasted the object back to all clients. And from the client side, removed the item from its current position and re-structured and appended it to its new position using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can have listener in client side as well for this event,

```
  io.sockets.on('status', function(data) {
   //do the update in client here
  });
```

And one other thing is you need to use `socket.broadcast.emit` here.Because  `socket.emit` will broadcast the message to all the clients with the client who is broadcasting the message.